# How to give a variable different random values every time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random


def random_letters():
   x = random.randrange(0, 28)
   for i in range (1,29):
   n = ["a", "b", "c", "ç", "d", "e", "f", "g", "ğ", "h", "ı", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "ö", "p", "r", "s", "ş", "t", "u", "ü", "v", "y", "z"]
   print (n[x], n[x], n[x], n[x], n[x], n[x], n[x], n[x], n[x], n[x], n[x], n[x], n[x], n[x], n[x], n[x], n[x])

random_letters()
```

The above is my attempt to print a random shuffling of letters each time the random_letters() method is called, though it does not work.  What approach can I use to generate this effect?

Comment: `random.choice(n)`?

Comment: Generate a range list, `shuffle` it, and then go through it printing the characters.

Comment: As a sidenote, I would recommend `[chr(ord('a') + i) for i in range(26)]` instead of that long abomination of a list declaration. Be clever about these things!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ good sidenote, even though OP has special characters in the list too, it'd be easier and better written to concatenate two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote doesn't work because `x = random.randrange(0, 28)` returns a single random number, when you print `n[x]` it's always going to be the same character. Even if you declared `x = random.randrange(0, 28)` inside the `for` loop, it wouldn't be enough to assure every character is different, simply because it would have to generate all different numbers in all loops, which is highly unprobable.

A workaround is creating a range list with the same length as your characters' list, then shuffling it with [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) and printing the characters' list using the indexes of the shuffled list:

```
from random import shuffle

def random_letters(length):
    n = ["a", "b", "c", "ç", "d", "e", "f", "g", "ğ", "h", "ı", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "ö", "p", "r", "s", "ş", "t", "u", "ü", "v", "y", "z"]
    list1 = list(range(len(n)))
    shuffle(list1) # Try printing list1 after this step
    for i in range(length):
        print(n[list1[i]],end="") # The end paramater is here to "concatenate" the characters

>>> random_letters(6)
grmöçd
>>> random_letters(10)
mbzfeıjkgş
```

Comment: I tried to change this a little bit. I wrote `list1 = list(range(6))` instead of `list1 = list(range(6))` but then it started to use only first 6 letters, how is it possible to avoid this with your method?

Comment: You want to pass a parameter that decides how long is the string? If yes, what you should modify is the for loop, use `for i in range(length):` and `print(n[list1[i]],end="")`.

Comment: Yes, for instance when I add something like `random_letters(int(input("letter_count")))` I want to have that amount of letters as my result.

Comment: `shuffle(list1)` just works fine as in your first example, can you please explain why did you changed it to `random.shuffle(list1)`.

Comment: Actually, since I've rewritten the code, I changed it without noticing, when importing modules, you can either use `from module import function` or `import module`, if the first is used, you should only call `function`, if the second is used you need to call `module.function`. I edited the answer to write back to this way and to put the code comments back, since I have forgot that too, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import numpy as np

n = np.array(["a", "b", "c", "ç", "d", "e", "f", "g", "ğ", "h", "ı", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "ö", "p", "r", "s", "ş", "t", "u", "ü", "v", "y", "z"])
nLength = np.arange(len(n))  #Generate an array from 0 to the length of n
np.random.shuffle(nLength)   #Randomly shuffle that array
def random_letters():
   m = n[nLength]            #Set m equal to a reordered n according to nLength
   print (m)

random_letters()
```

@coldspeed's method works rather well also, just make it a np.array as above for my method to work.

If you decide you only want it to return the same randomized string each time, set

```
np.random.seed(*some number*)
```

above the shuffle method.

Comment: If you were a beginner and someone shoved numpy on you, that'd be a lot to swallow. ;(

Comment: Hmm...a fair point.  Though a nice introduction to what will ultimately be a very useful library for them, no? :]